# For $X_n$ converges in measure to $X$, does it mean $|X|^p$ also converges in measure to $|X|^p$?

Tags: measure-theory

I think this is is not true for infinite measure since $f_n(x)=x+\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $f(x)=x$ but $f_n^2(x)$ doesn't converge in measure to $f^2(x)$. However, we are now dealing with random variables, which presumes the probability space with finite measure $1$. I think this should be true but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I think the one before last propertz answers your question : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure#Properties
The converse is not true part says that no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X_n \to X$ in measure implies $\phi\circ X_n \to \phi\circ X$ for any continuous function $\phi$ (in the case of a finite measure space). This is because $X_n \to X$ in measure iff every subsequence of $\{X_n\}$ has a further subsequence which converes almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much for this concise answer!